# Adverbs describing adverbs

Tags: grammar, adverbs, grammaticality-in-context

My understanding of adverbs is right?

> The deer ran really quickly.

**Really** describes the **adverb** **quickly** (**quickly** describes the **verb** **ran** hence is an **adverb** that's why I said so) hence **really** is an **adverb**.

Comment: Yes, of course. What else could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite their name, **adverbs** don't have to modify verbs; they can modify other parts of the sentence.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/adverb) defines an adverb as follows:

> A word or phrase that modifies or qualifies an adjective, verb, or other adverb or a word group, expressing a relation of place, time, circumstance, manner, cause, degree, etc.

You are correct about this sentence:

> The deer ran really quickly.

"Really" modifies "quickly", and the adverbial phrase "really quickly" modifies "ran".

Comment: I know what you mean, but strictly speaking it's the AdvP  "really quickly" that modifies "ran".

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for pointing that out.  I have amended my answer accordingly.